# Предыдущий перед

Tags: грамотная-речь

Обращаюсь к Вам, т.к. сам не филолог, а скорее программист-прикладник. В фразе - "предыдущая буква перед Л в слове февраль" мне ну так прям и чудится двойная ссылка на букву Р. Ход мысли:
(Л^.перед)^.предыдущая => Р
У меня съехала кровля или еще нет?

Извините, требуют какие-то очки уважения - поэтому сюда.

to Людмила.

Вы будете смеяться, но это фраза (точнее - фразы, их много) из УЧЕБНИКА (!) по информатике за 2-й класс (у дочки).

Пока ничего страшного, но покопался в учебнике и нарыл уже несколько логических ошибок. Вышеуказанную к ним ПОКА не отношу - выясняю суровую действительность. ))

Хотелось бы чёткого понимания - может ли быть вышеизложенное, при случае, основанием для ЮРИДИЧЕСКОГО (с привлечением филологов) обоснования? Согласен даже на ничью. )))

Впереди - контрольные, экзамены и т.п. И цена таких ошибок - дурацкие балы, могущие повлиять на дальнейшую судьбу!

Ёлки-палки:

1. Я вроде бы не должен говорить дочке, что учителя иногда неправы.
2. Я не хочу, чтобы от дебильного викторинного образования дочка стала тупой и/или з-ала свой мозг какой-то фигнёй.

Мне записки учителю передавать?

Comment: Фраза, я так понимаю, построена по аналогии со словосочетанием "следующий после". Ошибка тут, на первый взгляд, есть, но логика фразы совершенно ясна: указывается точка отсчёта и направление.

Comment: Напишите  всё  предложение  с  этой  фразой,  пожалуйста.

Comment: Это задача из учебника информатики 2й класс!!

"В слове ФЕВРАЛЬ предыдущая буква перед Л - [ ]"

Таких задач там - море. 17м весит пдф. Могу надёргать страничек.

Comment: Ну  это  вопрос  или  сообщение?  Знака  вопроса  нет.

Comment: Это задача такая. В [] малые дети буковки пишут. 
А я задал вопрос - таки Р или А правильно ?
Сомнения привёл выше, т.к. сам не филолог, а предмет - ЛОГИКА! Не изо, и не физ-ра.

Comment: "В слове ФЕВРАЛЬ предыдущая буква перед Л - [ ]". Это неправильная запись, здесь нет двух решений. Нельзя считать, что это буква Р, тогда надо записать: "Р - это предыдущая перед той буквой, которая стоит перед буквой Л". Поэтому здесь просто неграмотность, а не логическая задача повышенной трудности. И это, конечно, недопустимо.

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "предыдущая буква перед" неверно (это повтор), нужно использовать один из вариантов.

ПРИМЕР НА ТЕМУ

А) Две буквы СС пишутся в прилагательном, если основа исходного существительного заканчивается на "С" и ПЕРЕД "С" находится гласная: Парнас – парнасский.

Б) Одна буква С   пишется, если основа исходного существительного заканчивается на "С", а ПРЕДЫДУЩЕЙ буквой  является согласная: Уэльс  – уэльский.

Comment: to София.

Я не буду спорить с тем, что она (фраза) неправильная, но она - ЕСТЬ! (см. ниже)

Comment: Фраза  скорее  корявая,  чем  неправильная.  Объясните,  почему  вам  Р  чудится,  тоже  ведь  интересно.

Answer (score 1):

Если буквально понимать корявые фразы, ещё и не такое почудится. Человек просто хотел указать на точку отсчёта "предыдущей" буквы, отсюда плеоназм, ошибка. И филолог здесь не нужен, чтобы понять, что речь идёт о букве "а", только вот почему о ней, если она в сильной позиции и сомнений в её названии нет? Где Вы только такой пример изыскали?.. В головоломках для логистиков?

Comment: А дочка-то всё же как поняла? Дети иногда понятливей нас и не занимаются логистикой, не ищут ошибок. Может, это на их уровне понятно?

Comment: Дети, может, и не занимаются логистикой.   
Фраза - реальная задача по ЛОГИКЕ!

Comment: Логистика  это  наука  о  движении  товаров.  Здесь  -  логика.

Answer (score 0):

Штрафовать надо составителей таких учебников за их преступления против русского языка и здравого смысла. А детям лучше правду говорить: среди взрослых встречаются и не очень умные, и не очень грамотные.

Answer (score 0):

как я понимаю происхождение слова "предыдущий (пред-идущий)" - Идущий пред(перед) пример: предыдущий ролик мне понравился больше, т.е. речь идёт о том ролике, который был просмотрен перед последним, => что точка отсчёта, от которой нужно исходить - последний ролик. 
Моё понимание значения этого слова....
P.s. Всем Мира, Добра и прожить лет до 100!

Comment: Пожалуйста, при написании ответа ответа соблюдайте правила орфографии и пунктуации. Демонстративно игнорируя заглавные и запятые, вы проявляете неуважение к читающему.

Answer (score 0):

Во всей этой истории странно только то, что фраза из учебников *по информатике*. Там-то авторы должны проверять "алгоритм" того, что они понаписали.

В бытовой же речи (да в общем-то и в языке лингвистов) такого строго понимания просто нет. "Предыдущий перед X" воспринимается как "идущий перед Х" или синонимичное "предыдущий по отношению к Х". Связано, видимо, с тем, что "предыдущий" теряет семантику абсолютность ("предыдущий" - только по отношению к текущему, текущий при этом не указывается) и приобретает относительность, т. е. требует указания, по отношению к чему именно предыдущий.

Все сказанное, разумеется, не означает, что как-то оправдываю ошибку.